# Spark Job stuck writing dataframe to partitioned Delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Running databricks to read csv files and then saving as a partitioned delta table.

Total records in file are 179619219 .  It is being split on COL A (8419 unique values) and Year ( 10 Years) and Month.

```py
df.write.partitionBy("A","year","month").format("delta") \
  .mode("append").save(path)
```

Job gets stuck on the write step and aborts after running for 5-6 hours

Comment: really useful answer here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512207/partitionby-overwrite-strategy-in-an-azure-datalake-using-pyspark-in-databrick

Answer (score 2):

This is very bad partitioning schema. You simply have too many unique values for column `A`, and additional partitioning is creating even more partitions. Spark will need to create at least 90k partitions, and this will require creation a separate files (small), etc.  And small files are harming the performance.

For non-Delta tables, partitioning is primarily used to perform data skipping when reading data. But for Delta lake tables, partitioning *may* not be so important, as Delta on Databricks includes things like [data skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping), you can apply [ZOrder](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering), etc.

I would recommend to use different partitioning schema, for example, `year` + `month` only, and do OPTIMIZE with ZOrder on `A` column after the data is written.  This will lead to creation of only few partitions with bigger files.

Comment: sorry to ask some basic question , when I repartiton data based on some columns , how to check how many partitions it created , i see lot of skewness while writing data on delta table , how to handle this ? any samples or document on this ?

Comment: Simplest method - do `df.dropDuplicates(["col1", "col2"])` and the count...

Comment: I did not understand the rationale behind de-duplicates and number of partitions ..  given dropDuplicates only deletes any duplicate combination of col1 and col2 combination , right ? then how it gives number of partitions?

Comment: Do it on columns that you select for partitioning